# Foursquare OAuth token format

Tags: oauth, foursquare

As noted in [What are the characteristics of an OAuth token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115287) and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750 there is no defined valid characters for an OAuth token.

However, I've noticed that Foursquare seem to use only 48 ASCII {UPPER, DIGIT} characters, which is appropriate for GET requests (although case is ignored).

Are the Foursquare OAuth token validity rules documented somewhere, and can we be sure of the policy for future versions of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the current form of the OAuth token. There are no plans for it to change, but you should adhere to the spec and accept OAuth tokens of any form.

Comment: That being the spec that is no spec :-)